# Is there a maximum number of polygons that can be plotted using Folium/Leaflet.js from a JSON file?

Tags: folium

I have 15,000 parcels that I am trying to plot on a Folium map that is being served via Flask. I've imported the geojson as a layer, but when I include all 15,000 polygons, the map doesn't load. If I downsize that to 4,000 polygons, it loads great.

Is there a limit to the number of polygons that can be rendered? Are there any ways around this limit?